# Is it possible to stop a quiz when the player answers three questions wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have added a "lives" feature to my quiz. When the player answers three questions wrong, which means lives=0. The game should end but instead, it continues and goes pass zero to -1 and so on.

I have tried a while loop but I am not sure IF I have coded it correctly as it fails to work.

```
lives = 3
print ("lives =", lives)
print (" ")

name = input ("What is your name?")
print ("Hello",name,". Good Luck.")


while lives >= 0:
    ##is the player ready to start
    play = input ("Would you like to start? (Type Y for yes and N for no)")
    if play == "Y" or play == "y":
        from time import sleep
        sleep (1.0)
        print("Starting in...")
        sleep (1.0)
        print("3")
        sleep(1.0)
        print("2")
        sleep(1.0)
        print("1")
        break
    ##3, 2, 1 countdown added wk.4 friday
    elif play == "N" or play == "n":
        print ("End")
        break
    else:
        print ("That is not an answer.\n")


## 1st Question
question1 = ("1. What is Brisbanes AFL team called?")
options1 = (" a. Brisbane Tigers \n b. Brisbane Lions \n c. Brisbane Broncos \n d. Brisbane Magpies")
print (question1)
print (options1)
answer = input (">")
if answer == "B" or answer == "b":
    print ("Correct!")
else:
    print("Incorrect.")
    print ("lives =", lives - 1)
    lives-=1


## 2nd Question
question2 = ("2. What sport did Greg Inglis play")
options2 = (" a. rugby league \n b. rugby union \n c. AFL \n d. Soccer")
print (question2)
print (options2)
answer = input (">")
if answer == "A" or answer == "a":
    print ("Correct!")
else:
    print("Incorrect.")
    print ("lives =", lives - 1)
    lives-=1

## 3rd Question
question3 = ("3. Where were the 2018 Commonwealth Games held?")
options3 = (" a. Sunshine Coast \n b. Melbourne \n c. Brsbane\n d. Gold coast")
print (question3)
print (options3)
answer = input (">")
if answer == "D" or answer == "d":
    print ("Correct!")
else:
    print("Incorrect.")
    print ("lives =", lives - 1)
    lives-=1
```

The game should stop but instead continues saying the player is on negative lives. I would appreciate any help and thank you in advance for taking the time to help me with my problem. If you have any other pieces of advice that can better my quiz than feel free to comment.

Comment: Too much code - your code is also malformed - the indentation is borked. [edit} and fix it please - reduce your code to the minimal needed amount to replicate your problem: [mcve] - Thanks.

Comment: :< This looks very much like homework but whatever. Do you know the purpose of the first 'while' loop? It checks for lives for some reason but lives are never modified inside it. Its purpose is different. Now where would you check for lives? I'd say after or before every answer. You can try making a new loop for questions, but how do you keep track of which question to ask? You don't need a loop here, but can do if assignment says so. Now if you figured out how you want your lives checked, what do you want to do if they run out? What if you run out of questions to ask before that happens?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to game start again if lives = 0 then you need to include all your quiestions into while loop as well. And also include lives var into while loop so it will be set each time code enters loops, like:

```
lives = 3
print ("lives =", lives)
print (" ")

name = input ("What is your name?")
print ("Hello",name,". Good Luck.")


while lives >= 0:
    lives = 3
    ##is the player ready to start
    play = input ("Would you like to start? (Type Y for yes and N for no)")
    if play == "Y" or play == "y":
        print ('playing')
    ##3, 2, 1 countdown added wk.4 friday
    elif play == "N" or play == "n":
        print ("End")
        break
    else:
        print ("That is not an answer.\n")


    ## 1st Question
    question1 = ("1. What is Brisbanes AFL team called?")
    options1 = (" a. Brisbane Tigers \n b. Brisbane Lions \n c. Brisbane Broncos \n d. Brisbane Magpies")
    print (question1)
    print (options1)
    answer = input (">")
    if answer == "B" or answer == "b":
        print ("Correct!")
    else:
        print("Incorrect.")
        print ("lives =", lives - 1)
        lives-=1


    ## 2nd Question
    question2 = ("2. What sport did Greg Inglis play")
    options2 = (" a. rugby league \n b. rugby union \n c. AFL \n d. Soccer")
    print (question2)
    print (options2)
    answer = input (">")
    if answer == "A" or answer == "a":
        print ("Correct!")
    else:
        print("Incorrect.")
        print ("lives =", lives - 1)
        lives-=1

    ## 3rd Question
    question3 = ("3. Where were the 2018 Commonwealth Games held?")
    options3 = (" a. Sunshine Coast \n b. Melbourne \n c. Brsbane\n d. Gold coast")
    print (question3)
    print (options3)
    answer = input (">")
    if answer == "D" or answer == "d":
        print ("Correct!")
    else:
        print("Incorrect.")
        print ("lives =", lives - 1)
        lives-=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lives = 3
print ("lives =", lives)
print (" ")

name = input ("What is your name?")
print ("Hello",name,". Good Luck.")



##is the player ready to start
play = input ("Would you like to start? (Type Y for yes and N for no)")
if play == "Y" or play == "y":
    from time import sleep
    sleep (1.0)
    print("Starting in...")
    sleep (1.0)
    print("3")
    sleep(1.0)
    print("2")
    sleep(1.0)
    print("1")

##3, 2, 1 countdown added wk.4 friday
elif play == "N" or play == "n":
    print ("End")

else:
    print ("That is not an answer.\n")


while lives >= 0: # <----
    ## 1st Question
    question1 = ("1. What is Brisbanes AFL team called?")
    options1 = (" a. Brisbane Tigers \n b. Brisbane Lions \n c. Brisbane Broncos \n d. Brisbane Magpies")
    print (question1)
    print (options1)
    answer = input (">")
    if answer == "B" or answer == "b":
        print ("Correct!")
    else:
        lives -= 1 # <----
        print("Incorrect.")
        print ("lives =", lives) # <----
        if lives == 0: #<---
            break

    ## 2nd Question
    question2 = ("2. What sport did Greg Inglis play")
    options2 = (" a. rugby league \n b. rugby union \n c. AFL \n d. Soccer")
    print (question2)
    print (options2)
    answer = input (">")
    if answer == "A" or answer == "a":
        print ("Correct!")
    else:
        lives -= 1 # <----
        print("Incorrect.")
        print ("lives =", lives) # <----
        if lives == 0: #<---
            break


    ## 3rd Question
    question3 = ("3. Where were the 2018 Commonwealth Games held?")
    options3 = (" a. Sunshine Coast \n b. Melbourne \n c. Brsbane\n d. Gold coast")
    print (question3)
    print (options3)
    answer = input (">")
    if answer == "D" or answer == "d":
        print ("Correct!")
    else:
        lives -= 1 # <----
        print("Incorrect.")
        print ("lives =", lives) # <----
        if lives == 0: #<---
            break
```